# Solar wiring and code requirements

Tags: code-compliance, solar

Are the amp ratings the same for solar power as general electric supply to the house? I'm buying property and building my own home out of 2 converted large sheds with total of 736 ft². 2/2, w/d, garbage disposal and no dishwasher. What is a good rule of thumb with solar?

Comment: You are proposing **off-grid solar**, no backup supply?

Comment: Wouldn't that be _entirely_ dependent on what kind of solar system you're installing? Without knowing what brand/model/quantity of panels you're installing, we'd be guessing, just like you are.

Comment: I believe solar panels put out low voltage until it is converted the high(household) voltage.  So you might be dealing with two separate voltage systems and they have different wire gauge use, plus distance calculations.  You might need to use both the gauge tables for autos/boats and for house wire gauge.

Comment: Giving a lot of specs on the property and none on the solar system.  That suggests a very large knowledge gap that needs closing.  If anything can be said about solar/battery systems, you can't just slap rando stuff together and have it work. We get so many questions where someone is out of their depth on that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what wiring you are talking about.  If its unprocessed voltage form the solar panels, then no.  You need to spec the panels and then calculate what voltage/current you will generate.

If its from an inverter then yes the cable sizing will be the same.

From my calculations, even last year, it is not worth while having solar without storage.  That's for a grand average (over the year) of 5 hours of sunshine a day.  For off-grid, you definitely need storage.  I would spec the whole solar system first (including placement of all the components), before deciding on what wiring you need.

Additionally you will probably need gas or wood fired stoves.

Comment: There will be storage. I'll rely on the install company to install all the way to the inverter. I may even have wind power to back it up when it's stormy..